# Why is my tampermonkey script not deleting styles of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

So I currently have a tampermonkey script that runs when it's on `https://code.org/projects/applab/*` which is where I want it. However whenever I run my code to remove the attr 'style' of the grandparent and parent of the specified element nothing happens.
*Even though when I ran a test of this jQuery on w3's interpreter it worked...*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append(themeChangesCss);
    $("#screenSelector").parent().parent().removeAttr('style');
    $("#screenSelector").parent().removeAttr('style');
    $("#runButtonWrapper").parent().parent().removeAttr('style');
    $("#runButtonWrapper").parent().removeAttr('style');
});
```

You can also view the whole script here : https://sourceb.in/vdZOU1B7fq

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by logging the element you're trying to change to console. It is quite possible, that the web app changes the style AFTER your script executes. In that case, your changes will not have any effect.

If that is the case, read up on [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which allows you to execute code any time something changes the `style` attribute on the elements you want to clear.

I have tested your code and it indeed does work as it should on my test document. I couldn't find how should I test your code on the website you linked.

Comment: I can't find any information on mutation editors...

Comment: @Eh_asuna There is a tutorial here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver It has examples, try to copy one of them and edit it so that it works with your code.